# example.com cannot be resolved to an IP Address

Tags: networking, security, dns

since this morning I can't connect anymore to my website. I'm on a centos dedicated server with apache.

I think that there's a problem with DNS, this is the message I get from a webtool: example.com cannot be resolved to an IP Address.

DNSstuff reports two errors:

```
SOA record check
MX records check
```

My website has the problem of the recently-possible XSS attack for wordpress theme. https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/04/security-advisory-xss-vulnerability-affecting-multiple-wordpress-plugins.html I had not time to fix it.

What I'd like to know is: is it possible that a XSS attack caused this problem?

Comment: It's very unlikely that this is related to Wordpress XSS attacks, but since you obfuscated your domain name it's hard to tell what's wrong here.

Comment: If you tell us the actual domain name, we can troubleshoot.

Comment: At the very least, dig output to the address would help us get started.

Answer (score 0):

XSS would affect users to your site, not your site. That being said, since you're one of the users of your own site, it's possible your laptop or workstation or whatever was infiltrated and from it, passwords, cookies, token, etc stolen and then the attacker turned around and pwned your server.

But there's probably another explanation.